# Proof that the maximal slicing condition maximizes the volume

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I am  struggling with proving that the maximum slicing condition $$ K = 0 $$ not only extremizes, but  **maximizes** the volume $\mathcal{V}$ enclosed within a closed two-dimensional surface $S$.

The variation of the volume $\mathcal{V}_{t}$ of a domain $V \subset \Sigma_{t}$ (the last symbol denoting a spacelike hypersurface) is performed in such a way that the spatial coordinates describing the domain do not change in time. The volume of the domain is:

$$ V(t) = 
\int_{\mathcal{V_{t}}}\sqrt{\gamma}d^{3}x,$$
where $\gamma=\det\gamma_{ij}$ is the determinant of the 3-metric on a hypersurface.
The variation is perfomed along a vector field proportional to the coordinate time vector field $\partial_{t}$. The vanishing of this variation vector $v=\delta t \partial_{t}$ on the boundary $S$ implies that both the lapse function $\alpha$ and the shift vector field $\mathbf{\beta}$ vanish there.

As an example, the first variation is calculated to be:

$$ \frac{dV}{dt} = \int_{\mathcal{V_{t}}}\frac{\partial \sqrt{\gamma}}{\partial t}d^{3}x   = ... = -\int_{\mathcal{V}} \alpha K \sqrt{\gamma} d^{3}x.$$

Assuming the maximal slicing condition $K=0$ implies that the volume V enclosed by $S$ is extremized with respect to local variations in the direction of the coordinate time vector field.

Now, for the second time derivative of the volume, I do not really know how to proceed. The terms where the time derivative acts on anything but the $K$ will vanish once we assume maximal slicing. However, the expression involving $\frac{\partial K}{\partial t}$ is the term that I do not really see to be negative, as is required for the maximum.